# Using dynatable with meteor gives different results in fiddle and in real application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meteor

First of all this is my fiddle for the question : https://jsfiddle.net/ereday/82wzwem8/2/

As you can see from the fiddle, table header has a green background. Now let me share my code : [I have create a meteor project and just put these lines in my code]

**simple-todos.html**

```
<head>
    <title>simple-todos</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>

    {{> hello}}
    <table id="my-final-table">
        <thead>
            <th>Band</th>
            <th>Song</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>


<template name="hello">

    <button>Click Me</button>
    <p>You've pressed the button {{counter}} times.</p>
</template>
```

***simple-todos.js***

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    // counter starts at 0
    Session.setDefault('counter', 0);

    Template.hello.helpers({
        counter: function () {
            return Session.get('counter');
        }
    });

    Template.hello.events({
        'click button': function () {
            // increment the counter when button is clicked
            Session.set('counter', Session.get('counter') + 1);
            var jsondata=[
                {
                    "band": "Weezer",
                    "song": "El Scorcho",
                    "id":1
                },
                {
                    "band": "Chevelle",
                    "song": "Family System",
                    "id":2
                }
            ];

            $('#my-final-table').dynatable({
                table: {
                    headRowSelector:'thead',
                },
                dataset: {
                    records: jsondata
                }
            });



            //
        }
    });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.startup(function () {
        // code to run on server at startup
    });
}
```

These are all the codes inside my meteor folder. So I get the following screen on my localhost : https://www.dropbox.com/s/r1377i8ddjb4yg9/Screenshot%202015-09-02%2018.15.49.png?dl=0

Why there are differences between them ? And how could I fix my own one ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the CSS. I'm not sure if you use a Dynatable Meteor package or directly put the dynatable js in your own code base. It seems however that you are either missing a css file or using a different one.

Comment: I'm using meteor 0.6.5.1 therefore I had to put dynatable files into my project manually. I put dynatable.js and dynatable.css files under client/lib folder @JeroenPeeters

Comment: I'm not sure if css is picked up automatically. Try putting the css in public/css. Then, in the client folder create a file head.coffee with

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/dynatable.css">
</head>